# Quarkus Azure Functions Service Bus Topic Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, quarkus, azure-servicebus-topics

has anyone tried to use Quarkus 3 with Azure Functions, specifically with Service Bus Topic Trigger. Everything is working fine local, but when i deploy it to my Function App, using Azure pipelines, function does appear on Azure portal, and all files associated with it too, but when it is actually triggered, i encountered ClassNotFoundException and function can't be executed successfully.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Azure Function with Service bus trigger Java is not supported with Quarkus. According to this [Quarkus document](https://quarkus.io/guides/azure-functions) and this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-quarkus) Azure has built in support for Http Trigger.

The Quarkus extension also does not have Azure service bus trigger, Refer below:-

[image]

According to the Quarkus document you need to run below commands in order to deploy the Quarkus function in Azure.
When I tried deploying the Quarkus function via Azure devops pipeline or VS code the function does not appear in the portal, You need to use the commands below:-

```bash
az login
./mvnw clean package azure-functions:deploy
```

**Output:-**

***Ran the Function locally:-***

[image]

***Deployed the Function in Azure:-***

[image]

[image]

Add https://portal.azure.com in the CORS settings to run the Qurakus Function on Portal like below:-

[image]

[image]

If you want to use Service bus with java you can refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues?tabs=connection-string)

Comment: Yes there is azure-functions-http library, and azure-functions generic library. But i believe as from i could i see while researching, that azure-functions library should and can be used for each trigger type. I believe that given document is only Http because they are familiar to it and made example with it. And also, as i said, i am able to use quarkus and service bus topic trigger local, everything is working as expected. I will try to deploy it like you said, not from azure devops pipelines, maybe that will make it work.